# Passing multiple value and setter pairs to Context.Provider in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All the documentation and blog posts I've managed to find so far only deals with a single [value, setValue] pair scenario. In my case I would like/need to pass multiple pairs of [value, setValue] variables to a Provider using the useContext hook.

Here is the typical example I setup in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/nardove/pen/XWrZRoE?editors=0011

```
const App = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <MyProvider>
                <ComponentA />
            </MyProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

const MyContext = React.createContext();
const MyProvider = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("foo");
    return(
        <MyContext.Provider value={[value, setValue]}>
            {props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
}

const ComponentA = () => {
const [value, setValue] = React.useContext(MyContext);
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>
                The value is: {value}
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

If you can share any ideas on how pass multiple [value, setValue] pairs to the Provider or an alternative to my problem will be much appreciated

Comment: @Andy The OP is asking for useContext. Your comment entails that the OP change his question's topic rather than offer a solution.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella - `useState` and `useReducer` are similar - they can both be used in conjunction with `useContext`. I recommended `useReducer` as an alternative to `useState` because it's more useful for more complex states. Granted - my comment wasn't particularly helpful though.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[`Context.Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) accepts any value, so you can try passing an object:

```
<MyContext.Provider
  value={{ value: [value, setValue], value2: [value2, setValue2] }}
>
  {props.children}
</MyContext.Provider>;
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <ComponentA />
    </MyProvider>
  );
};

const MyContext = React.createContext();

const MyProvider = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("foo");
  const [value2, setValue2] = React.useState("goo");

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={{ value: [value, setValue], value2: [value2, setValue2] }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ComponentA = () => {
  const { value, value2 } = React.useContext(MyContext);
  const [stateValue, setStateValue] = value;
  const [stateValue2, setStateValue2] = value2;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>The value is: {stateValue}</h1>
      <h1>The value2 is: {stateValue2}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

---

Notice that there is a caveat when trying to optimize useless renders (be sure you not just [optimizing prematurely](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)): there is [**no render bailout for Context Consumers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985555/render-only-updated-items-in-an-array/64985673#64985673).

> As for v17, may be change in near future.

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm, now on to the next one ;)

Comment: I was stuck for day on this, you have no idea how much this helped me.

Comment: i cannot add in my usestate setter into my context. initialisation has error because hooks cannot be used outside a component. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.value1'). TypeError: setInnerModalType is not a function. (In 'setInnerModalType('request')', 'setInnerModalType' is undefined)

Comment: @wly185 Please open a separate question, we need more context than that.

Comment: <MyContext.Provider
      value={{ value1: [value1, setValue1], value2: [value2, setValue2] }}
    >

why this is not working ?

Comment: What is not working? Need more context than that.

Answer (score 13):

To pass in multiple state values to a provider, you just need to create another state object and pass it in.

But inlining these comes with a [caveat](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) mentioned in the docs. Since the object (and arrays) in render are created every render, they lose the referential equality and hance any components connected to this context will need to refresh.

To get around this in a functional component, you can use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to memoise the value and refresh only when one of these values change.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();
const MyProvider = (props) => {
    const [valueA, setValueA] = React.useState("foo");
    const [valueB, setValueB] = React.useState("bar");
    const providerValue = React.useMemo(() => ({
        valueA, setValueA,
        valueB, setValueB,
    }), [valueA, valueB]);
    return(
        <MyContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
            {props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: I get the error that value `is not assignable to type 'null'`

Comment: `useMemo` is used so that any parent rerendering does not generate a new instance of context. [See More](https://blog.agney.dev/useMemo-inside-context/)

Comment: for anyone who came here looking to make memo of setter function that is used to set the context object value, I used `useCallback` by wrapping the function as below.

    `const updateContextState = useCallback((value: updateContextType) => {
        setContextState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...value }))
    }, [])`

Comment: and that function is safe to export as below

  `const context = useMemo(() => ({
        userID: contextState.userID, updateContextState: updateContextState
    }), [contextState.userID, updateContextState])

    return <LoginUserContext.Provider value={context}>
        {props.children}
    </LoginUserContext.Provider>`

Answer (score 3):

Create `Provider` component contains:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
export const Context = React.createContext();

const Provider = props => {
    const [value1, setValue1] = useState("");
    const [value2, setValue2] = useState("");

    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{ value1, setValue1, value2, setValue2 }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
};

export default Provider;
```

And in your `app`:

```
<Provider>
   <ComponentA/>
</Provider>
```

Then in your `ComponentA`:

```
const { value1, setValue1, value2, setValue2} = useContext(Context);
```

Now you can use each value or set new value for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can send values as shown below. I have sent demo1, setdemo1, demo2, and setdemo2. Inside the {{}} inside exportValues.provider It worked for me

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';

export const exportValues = createContext();

const ContextTab = ({children}) => {
  const [demo1, setdemo1] = useState([]);
  const [demo2, setdemo2] = useState([]);
  return (
    <exportValues.Provider
      value={{demo1, setdemo1,demo2, setdemo2}}>
      {children}
    </exportValues.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextTab;
```