# Why would I use 'useReduce' in react while implementing global scoped states?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So after coding a complete web application with react with props-drilling so deep like you've never seen before, you shouldn't, I've decided to give react 'contexts' a go. I read the react documentation, and I've decided to make my states(which seriously need help because they're so deeply rooted into components after components) in a separate file:

-create a 'context.js' filee

-Inside I'm gonna have: [and notice I have two states inside]

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
export const context = createContext();
export default function ContextProvider (props) {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState();
    const [state2, setState2] = useState();
    return (
        <context.provider value={[state1, setState1, state2, setState2]}>
            props.children
        </context.provider>
       )
}
```

- Now all I have to do is import this component where I want to make these states visible, use destructuring like so:

```
//inside a functional component
...
const [state1, setState1] = useContext(context); //assuming I only need state1 in this component
...
```

Now my question is how efficient this approach is. And in some blogs I read about using context with hooks, every one I read used 'useReduce' hook. Could someone explain why 'useReduce' was used, that is what problem does it solve and how. That'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this this question is pretty relevant here: [Fast changing states without Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055446/fast-changing-states-without-redux/) (at the end of the day, `useReducer` and `useState` should be equally efficient in terms of performance? I'm not an expert here though).
Also, `useReducer` is better for handling complex state, which usually happens when you start using Contexts or Redux.

If you want to have an object like this in your state

```
user: {
  options: { ... },
  settings: { ... }
}
```

You REALLY should use `useReducer` (especially if you're in a situation where changing in the `options` relies on knowing what the `settings` are) and have the complicated logic be handled through the dispatch, rather than jumping through hoops and trying to get it to work with `useState`. At the end of the day, they do pretty much the same thing in that they "handle state", if you want to know more about the nuances, best way to do it is to read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer.

Again, I'm not an expert but I've made a fair few attempts at looking into "performance in React" and from what I've gathered, rerenders due to state change are rarely the problem. Usually you'll have something in a child component that relies on performing an expensive calculation on a prop, and the correct solution isn't to "prevent the rerender" but instead to do something like "move the expensive calculation up" so it only needs to happen once per render rather than `n children` per render.